# .NET CLR Smallest Memory Allocation (32/64-bit)

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, clr

I'm trying to get to the bottom of the lowest block of memory that can be allocated via the CLR in both 32-bit and 64-bit systems.  It seems to me that on a 32-bit system, it will allocate in 4 byte chunks and on 64-bit it will allocate in 8 byte chunks.  If true, does an Int32 need 8 bytes of address space on 64-bit system?

Comment: The CLR doesn't allocate per instance of objects. Instead it allocates in large segments as needed and these are then used to hold objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the following code:

```
public class Numbers
{
    public Int16 A = 1;
    public Int32 B = 2;
    public Int64 C = 3;
    public UInt16 D = 4;
    public UInt32 E = 5;
    public UInt64 F = 6;
    public short G = 7;
    public int H = 8;
}
```

Compiling and running that using x64 as a target platform yields the following instructions when viewed in the Disassembly view:

```
7:         public Int16 A = 1;
mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+50h]  
mov         word ptr [rcx+24h],1  

 8:         public Int32 B = 2;
mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+50h]  
mov         dword ptr [rcx+18h],2  

 9:         public Int64 C = 3;
mov         ecx,3  
movsxd      rcx,ecx  
mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp+50h]  
mov         qword ptr [rax+8],rcx  

10:         public UInt16 D = 4;
mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+50h]  
mov         word ptr [rcx+26h],4  

11:         public UInt32 E = 5;
mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+50h]  
mov         dword ptr [rcx+1Ch],5  

12:         public UInt64 F = 6;
mov         ecx,6  
movsxd      rcx,ecx  
mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp+50h]  
mov         qword ptr [rax+10h],rcx  

13:         public short G = 7;
mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+50h]  
mov         word ptr [rcx+28h],7  

14:         public int H = 8;
mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+50h]  
mov         dword ptr [rcx+20h],8  
mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+50h]
```

From this you can see that it allocates 2, 4, and 8 bytes depending on the datatype. It isn't so that it allocates in chunks of the wordsize of the processor, on Windows a word is always 16 bits, a double word is always 32 bits, and on x64 you have quadruple words.

To prove it you can view the address space in memory and how the values are stacked up:

[image: ![Memory block allocations]

Now you must note that since all memory as managed by the CLR, this is not always a predictable behavior. As you see from my example, it allocated 8 bytes for an Int64 and a UInt64, 4 bytes for an Int32, UInt32 and an int, and only 2 bytes for a UInt16 and a short.

If we were to use even smaller numbers, such as byte or bool like this:

```
public class Numbers
{
    public byte I = 10;
    public bool J = true;
}
```

We get another result:

```
 7:         public byte I = 10;
mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+50h]  
mov         byte ptr [rcx+8],0Ah  

 8:         public bool J = true;
mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+50h]  
mov         byte ptr [rcx+9],1
```

Now it uses bytes, and uses only 1 byte per.

[image: Allocation of 2 bytes]

The object lives on the heap in a chunk of 64 bits:
[image: Object viewed on the heap]

However it isn't always so that the CLR will organize this in memory this way.
As you can see from the heap map, the CLR allocated a chunk of 64 bytes for the object, and tries to fit all the object pieces inside there. It does so using as much cleverness as possible.

I tried several different versions of this, and the allocation space depends on behavior, and if the CLR allocates too little, it will reallocate somewhere else and move the pointer, for instance the first 8 bytes of the address space is used to hold the 3, it then has some of the object related data in the first 4 bytes, thus sharing the 8 bytes with other data. And it will continue to do so until it needs that space to hold the value for 'C'. One way it does that is to see if it can shift C up to gain the occupied space.

So to answer your question the smallest chunk it will allocate will vary on the application and how the CLR chooses to organize memory for your program. You shouldn't think of your types as chunks of memory, think that their size represent the maximum needed memory to hold the max/min values of them.

A good rule of thumb is to think that it allocates the maximum required space the type calls for, rounded to bytes, but since the CLR will manage all this for you, you do not really need to worry about it. Memory considerations on .NET should be focused on object creation and life-cycle management, not value types.

Comment: You allocated those items as local variables, so they are on the stack and not on the heap. IMHO, on the heap, the overhead is significant. On the other hand side, allocating an array is quite efficient, since only the array will have a header, not each individual item.

Comment: There should not be much of a difference between 32 bit and 64 bit, since the .NET datatypes have defined lengths, e.g. Int16 will always be 16 bit.

Comment: They are public fields of a class, instanced from main. They are not on the stack, they live within their object on the heap. The address shows this, the object gets a 64 byte long chunk to live in. And as you say the difference between x32 and x64 is that instead of allocating two dwords for 64bit datatypes, it uses qwords, and uses other instructions to manipulate them.